# Sony DRE-777 Sampling Reverb

Tags: convolution, reverb, impulse-response, gear, sound-design

I have access to a Sony DRE-S777 Convolution Reverb, and we're trying to figure out how to sample for it.  Does anyone know what format the samples need to be?

Do I need to to a sweep?  How long?  Speaker / Mic setup?  File Format?

These guys are pretty rare, so I'd be surprised if anyone knows, but it's worth a shot!

P.S.  I have both the user's manual and the quick start guide.  Neither touch on the subject :-/

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I know that the machine has a sampling function in it, but the unit is built in to the stage I'm working on, and I can't bring it around with me to sample environments.  I'd like to find a way to do the sample elsewhere, then bring it back to the machine later on.

---

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so I've done a bit more research and here's what I've found out so far:

In order to do the sampling internally, you have you have an option called the DASK-S704. It's basically a CD-Rom that the unit boots from. Not sure if we have one of those. I'll have to find out. If we don't, I may be SOL, as the unit is discontinued...

However, I'm still wondering if there's a way to create the samples and load them in without using this software, and without taking the Sony unit on location. There may not be, but I'm going to try, try, try until I get a definitive answer!

Comment: There must be a manual somehwere...or an email/phone call to Sony tech support?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the Sony working without the memory stick or at least where to find a new memory stick? I only have the discs...someone stole the memory sticks

Comment: I have 3 Sony Sampling Reverb discs for sale. DASK-701 (Eurpoean Halls and Churches), DASK-702(American Acoustic Spaces), and DASK-703 (Japanese Acoustic Spaces. Let me know if you'd like them. gordiegerm@verizon.net

Answer (score 1):

You MUST have the Sony re S777/2. AND DASK-S704 Ver.2.0 "Sampling your Spaces" CD ROM and Memory stick with CD-ROM Licence.  A Sony manual for this exists as well.  I was right on it after buying my unit and was able to buy every option and CD set Sony ever made.  Thank God!! It was NOT Easy to find the sampling software!!!  It works Great I can tell you.Good luck, you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, if you want to sample IRs you HAVE to use the DRE777 on the field and the optionnal "self sampling CD-Rom" from Sony...

I'm pretty sure there are no other options to do it...

hope this helps